# What should I do if the refrigeration compressor returns oil？

Tags: compressor

When I was using my refrigerator, I noticed that it returned a little oil. What should I do?

Comment: What on earth are  you saying happened?  Where did this oil come from inside your refrigerator? Were you attempting to service it? Does the refrigerator cool normally?

Comment: Olive oil?   Screw the cap on tighter.

Answer (score 2):

How do you "use" a refrigerator and get oil? That said, home refrigeration units are *completely*, hermetically sealed.

That said, is the refrigerator working normally?

- If it is, and you see or feel oil on it, likely it dripped from somewhere else, or was deposited from oil evaporated and sprayed up during frying. You might clean it off *gently* with dish detergent and water, after unplugging the refrigerator.
- If it's *not* working, you can't fix a refrigerant leak yourself. Get ti fixed by a professional, or replace it.